# Infinite while loop with continue keyword

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, iteration

My problem - and I don't know why there is a keyword `continue`, which should leave the value of 3 and go further. In fact, I have a loop that is infinite - that is, it crashes the program.

```
tab = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
i = 0
while i < len(tab):
    print(tab[i])
    if tab[i] == 3:
        continue
    i+=1
```

Comment: `continue` keeps the loop going.  `break` leaves the loop.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to iterate through the list until you find a `3` then `break`. Do something like this:

```py
items = [1,2,3,4,5]
for item in items:
   if item == 3:
       break
```

The keyword `continue` will pass to the next iteration of the loop, where `break` will stop the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `continue` keyword continues with the next iteration of the loop.

In your case, it prevents the statement `i+=1` to be executed.

Here is what happens:

1. Loops through 0,1,2 just fine
2. When it evaluates `tab[i] = 3` it proceeds with the next iteration of the loop and `i+=1` is never executed, hence `i` remains 3 and never gets incremented. It keeps doing this forever.

If you want to exit the loop, you can use the `break` statement instead of `continue`.

For more information, you can read on the `continue` keyword here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the answers here all assume that OP wanted to use `break` instead of `continue`.

However, if you need to use continue in a while loop, make sure you have an increment/decrement operation ***above*** the continue statement, because the continue statement jumps to the top of the while loop and, in your case, `i` remains 3.

Respectively, the `continue` statement in a do-while loop jumps to the bottom of the loop. So, in your case you have two options, either you increment above the continue or use a for-loop.

```
tab = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
i = -1
while i < len(tab):
    i += 1
    print(tab[i])
    if tab[i] == 3:
        continue
```

OR

```
for i in range(0,15):
    if i == 3:
       continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: Too many people are unnecessarily assuming that OP wants to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `continue` keyword, but I think you want `break`.

Your code is running forever because `i` never iterates past 3. Once `i == 4`, it enters your if statement and continues the loop. Since it continues, it never iterates after that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the `continue` keyword that skips the rest of the code.
Once i reaches 3, it skips over the `i+=1` command.  It appears that you want to use the keyword `break`.  You could also do:

```
for i in tab:
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to skip the value "3" then

```
tab = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
i = 0
while i < len(tab)-1:
    i+=1
    if tab[i] == 3:
        continue
    //i+=1 => infinite loop
    print(tab[i])
```